# SQL and PHP: Find all "assets" connected to "presentation"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oop

I really need some help with some SQL.

**Question 1:**

It's easy enough to get all "assets" that belong to a "presentation" if the asset has a corresponding "presentationid" within it's table.

```
SELECT * FROM asset WHERE presentationid = 3
```

But how to I accomplish the same thing by joining? What's the best way to say:

`SELECT * FROM asset WHERE ...` asset is connected to presentation via "presentationasset":

```
TABLE asset
id
name

TABLE presentation
id
name

TABLE presenationasset
id
presentationid
assetid
```

I hope this makes sense. I want to list out all of the actual assets and their columns, not the association table. :)

**Question 2:** (not as important)

I have my application setup so that "presentation" is a class and "asset" is a class...

With question 1 in mind, how do I return each of the associated assets as "asset" objects? Or does that even matter?

Comment: If they're so cool, would you mind posting an example using my tables above?

Comment: Regarding Q2: There is no way to simply convert a database record to an object...  That's where the fun stuff is ;).  Either use an ORM (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library) or you'll have to write the translation layer yourself.

Comment: @ChrisLively, thanks for responding. It actually doesn't matter in this case... I just need to be able to get the IDs and such in order to pass that information long for a save. Thanks for shooting over that link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name
FROM asset a 
JOIN presentationasset pa ON pa.assetid = a.id AND pa.presentationid = 3
JOIN presentation p ON p.id = pa.presentationid
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, hkf! That seems to work great! Can I also ask you about question #2?

Answer (score 1):

Fair enough :)

```
Select * from asset where id in
(select assetid from presentationasset where id in
(select id from presentation where name = "whateva"))
```

or

```
Select * from asset where id in
(select assetid from presentationasset where presentationid = 3)
```

Comment: Wow, honestly, I've never used sub-queries before. This is great!

Comment: @dcolumbus A warning, especially in MySQL they can be extremely inefficient! Make sure to check your explain plan.